# Sharing App functionality in android

Tags: android

I want to create a share app functionality in my app. I have seen various topics where they share text or links of app. But I want to share it offline, e.g. via bluetooth or shareit. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). This is not a free code-writing service nor tutorial site. You're expected to have already done basic research, to present the code you've tried with a description of how it's not working and what the expected result would be. As it stands, your question is "too broad".

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html
Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your question. So to clear this out, i want to tell you that you can share your app contents using Content Provider, that you can build yourself or you can use the default ones.

But again, your target could not be achieved, because firstly you have to make/create a Network to transfer using bluetooth or wifi network(that shareIt does).

Secondly, there should be some app, which itself have content provider uri to share your contents in their app through bluetooth or wifi network.

Hope this helps you to understand your problem well.

Comment: can you please give an example